# How to change buttonImage dynamically for single instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

We are creating multiple instances of datepicker, when selecting particular date from one datepicker that time we need to change the buttonImage of that datepicker instance only not 
all.

Please refer below code

```
$('.FixedDates').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/HM-Cal-Icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});

$('.AddDate').click(function () {
    $('.HMDatePicker').append('<br><input type="text" class="FixedDates">');
    $('.FixedDates').datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/HM-Cal-Icon.png",
              buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

How to change the buttonImage of current datepicker  instead of multiple instance of datepicker

like

```
$('.FixedDates').datepicker("option", "buttonImage", 'CalendarBlank.jpg');
```

above code will change the buttonImage for all instance of datepickers. i want to change the current instance of datepicker buttonImage which one actually clicked.

Please find below fiddle link..
http://jsfiddle.net/KN4az/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the icon in the `onSelect` callback, that way only the image for the currently selected datepicker is changed when a date is selected.

There's also the `onClose` callback for when the datepicker closes, if that's more appropriate

```
var settings = {
    showOn          : "button",
    buttonImage     : "images/HM-Cal-Icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly : true,
    onSelect        : function() {
        $(this).datepicker("option", "buttonImage", 'CalendarBlank.jpg');
    }
}

$('.FixedDates').datepicker(settings);

$('.AddDate').click(function () {
    $('.HMDatePicker').append('<br><input type="text" class="FixedDates">');
    $('.FixedDates').datepicker(settings);
});
```

To just change the options for one datepicker at any time, you'll have target it by something unique, for instance the index, which can be done with `eq()`, which is zero based, so the below would change the icon for the second datepicker with that class

```
$('.FixedDates').eq(1).datepicker("option", "buttonImage", 'CalendarBlank.jpg');
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in some other button click event ? like inside datepicker am going to display some buttons. so when button is clicked i need to change the image.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, you just have to target the datepicker relative to the button using jQuery DOM traversal like `closest`, `prev` or whatever fits.

Comment: actually the button is inside the datepicker. consider am going to add clear button bottom of datepicker ,after selecting date the date will be updated in textbox. so the clear button is used to clear the textbox value. i want to change the button image when clear button is clicked which is placed bottom of datepicker

Comment: Then you probably want closest, something like `$('.clearbutton').click(function() { $(this).closest('.hasDatepicker').datepicker("option", "buttonImage", 'CalendarBlank.jpg'); })`

Comment: It should noted that the datepicker popup is usually appended to the bottom of the DOM, and is dynamic, so you probably need a delegated event handler and some creative DOM traversal.